# How do these elements fade out on this site?

Tags: javascript, html

How do these sites implement fading effect?

Notice this site carefully:

http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/06/best-html5-media-player-implementations/

As you scroll down, you see a little fade effect for images/videos etc. It only happens once. Can anybody let me know how is this done?

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the jquery tag from your question, because it assumes that it is jquery-related, which is not necessarily the case. I do not see the effect you are talking about, so my first thought was whether you are trying to spam. You can of course look at the website with Firebug to see what they are using.

Comment: @mydoghasworms : See the responses that I received. Few have already answered which shows I am not spamming. Stop being crazy.

Comment: please don't take it personally. You never know these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is done with jQuery and the lazyload jQuery plugin.  The plugin is available here:  http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

It's very simple to use, you tag all the images you'd like to load with a class, like `.lazy`.  Then you use this to "select" for those tagged images and the plugin does the heavy lifting.  You have to include the jQuery library file and the plugin file with `<script>` tags, and then a simple script kicks it off:

```
jQuery(".lazy").lazyload({ 
    placeholder : "http://mysite.com/placeholder.gif",
    effect : "fadeIn"
});
```

This puts the placeholder image in until you scroll into view, and uses the fadeIn effect to display the image.

Comment: Glad I could help.  jQuery will change the way you think about JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are using jQuery LazyLoad plugin for this effect.